# How to auto save in 5 sec interval using jQuery or javascript in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("form").submit(function(){
                alert("submitted");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How to change the code so that i can autosave the entered information in 5 sec or above. For example in Django I have these fields:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    published_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)    
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    context = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
```

**So the condition should be if either something is written in title or text it should autosave in 5 second.**

This is the html code for input of title and text

```
<div class="col-sm-12 title">
  {{ adminform.form.title }}
</div>

 <div class="col-sm-12 title">
    {{ adminform.form.text }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            save();
        });

        function save(){
             setTimeout( function(){ 
                     $("form").submit(function(){
                     alert("submitted");
                 });
          }  , 5000 ); // in ms
        }
</script>
```

On you html code for your title and text you can add a attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" oninput="save();">
```

Comment: What if my HTML code is like this for title and text:

<div class="col-sm-12 title">
                                {{ adminform.form.title }}
                            </div>

 <div class="col-sm-12">
                                {{ adminform.form.text }}
                            </div>

Comment: You said you can edit the text so i guess that you use some form of input right, if your question is about changing the static content of you div exemple above you can add a refresh function after the alert like this: window.location.reload(true);

Comment: But it'll be a bit messy so i suggest you to use Ajax for dynamic content like yours

Comment: I tried this code, it does not work with the condition of auto save if something is written in text or title

Comment: Hmm i don't know what's wrong it should work maybe you're missing something... try to double check your code

Comment: It works but not the way I wanted. I wanted the file to be saved after 5 sec automatically when I write some thing in the title or text input box without clicking submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var save = function () {
        setTimeout(
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/api/article/{{article.id}}/',
                data: $("#article_form").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('submitted')
                }
        }), 5000);
    }
    save()
</script>
```

Can we do the solution by using ajax. i am not familiar with ajax so I donot know whether this code works or not